# Swift Protocol delegation not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `viewController` that has a `containerView` with `pageView`. Once I slide a view from the pageView I want to call a function in the viewController I have tried with my code below but it is calling `buttonMaskColor` please where would be my issue?

```
class PlaceMenuDetailsViewController: UIViewController, PageViewSliderDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        detailsButton.pageDelegation = self
    }

    func buttonMaskColor(){
        println("delegate work")
    }
}
```

---

```
class DetailPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    weak var pageDelegation:PageViewSliderDelegate?

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    pageDelegation?.buttonMaskColor()

    var page = (viewController as! PageDelegate).pageNumber + 1
    return viewControllerForPage(page)
}
```

Comment: "but it is calling buttonMaskColor" or not calling ?

Comment: No it is not calling it. @Ramshad

Comment: I think DetailPageViewController's page view delegate is nil. Try adding delegate = self on viewDidLoad of DetailPageViewController

Comment: I have added `delegate = self` but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign self to pageDelegation in your prepareForSegue function in your mainView after giving and identifier for the embed segue like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "embedSegueIdentifier" {

        let distinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailPageViewController

        distinationVC?.pageDelegation = self

    }

}
```

Comment: Thats works but may I ask why it is calling the  `func buttonMaskColor()` at the first slide?

Comment: That's because your are calling it in viewControllerAfterViewController and that function is executed each time the page view controller state changes, including the first time it is displayed. would you please explain what you want in a different question so I can help you. upvote and accept please if it worked.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand viewControllerAfterViewController?

Comment: yes the function you are calling pageDelegation?.buttonMaskColor() in.

Comment: It is just calling twice at the first slide and then all the time only once. So there is no way to solve that right?

Comment: well you can achieve this by making another delegation between your view and the pageViewController and call it in the view's viewDidAppear function and then in that delegation function you can call your buttonMaskColor function.